# Upload Only Image jpg, jpeg,bmp,gif and png. how write code in this code

Tags: c#

if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

```
if (extension == ".jpg")
{
    FileUpload1.SaveAs("yourpath" + FileUpload1.FileName);

}
else
{
Response.Write("Only .Jpg allowed");
}
```

}

Comment: are you referring c# .net ?

Comment: @shail what is that question supposed to mean?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try following :

```
            string[] imageTypes = {"jpg", "jpeg","bmp","gif", "png"};
            string filename = "abc.jpg";
            Boolean validFileName = imageTypes.Contains(filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf(".") + 1).ToLower());
```

Comment: This will not work if the uploaded file's name ends in a dot, or has a non-lowercase extension.

Comment: CodeCaster : you are referring to invalid file names.  My code works with valid file extensions.

Comment: What I mention (files ending in a dot and files with not entirely lowercase extensions) are **not** invalid filenames. This code is not robust.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the ones reference.  I added ToLower() to handle both upper and lower case.  My answer should not be getting a negative rating.